# AWS: How to import a simple function as a Lambda layer?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

So we are using python Lambda functions and Textract for keyword searches. We would like to index our Textract processed data in into Elasticsearch.

So we downloaded the elasticsearch package with pip at this path:

- `python/lib/python3.8/site-packages`
- or at this one: `python`

and zipped the `python` folder.

We created a new layer with this .zip and added it to our Lambda function. When testing the Lambda function we get the error message:

> No module named 'elasticsearch'

What did we do wrong here? We are new to AWS and have been trying for hours and at this point we are stuck. By the way we succeeded when trying to import a simple pyyhon file containing a hello world.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Once I had problem when I packaged layer on Windows machine. Same directory packaged on linux machine worked fine.

Comment: Was this the way you packaged the code: [Build an AWS Lambda Deployment Package for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/) Also, which line triggered the error? Was it the `import elasticsearch` statement?